# How to configure alexa to activate my arduino using the web interface I created?

Tags: arduino, alexa-skills-kit

I created an arduino circuit with an relay output turn on/off circuits, and I send commands using a cellphone app through web. Each arduino has an IP address and the commands are sent by wifi by accessing their website. For example, to turn relay 01 on I simply access 192.168.0.101/on and to turn if off I access 192.168.0.101/off. This is configured as buttons in my cellphone app and that's it.

However, I would like to configure voice commands in Alexa, using routines maybe?, so when I say "alexa turn relay 01 on" it would access the respective website.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however it's not as simple as just visiting a website in your local network.

If you take a look how integrations with smart bulbs are implemented, you'll find out that every device is controlled through some cloud (service responsible for changing the state of the device needs to be available from the Internet).

Here you can find the [tutorial](https://docs.arduino.cc/arduino-cloud/tutorials/alexa-mkr-rgb-shield).